Ryu-Takayanagi surface for geometry containing closed timelike curve
Is the Ryu-Takayanagi formulation (and its extensions) applicable for spacetimes containing closed timelike curves (CTCs)?
I have gone through the assumptions that go into their formulation but as far as I understand there is no such restriction. But I think with CTCs the argument of Lewkowycz and Maldacena might not go through (although I have not worked out the details).
Any reference which attempts to do the RT calculation in spacetimes with CTCs, or an explanation for why it might breakdown will be helpful?
